# Get Android's CPU tempareture on NativeActivity

Tags: android

How can I get the CPU tempareture on NativeActivity?
I think, I should use jclass and FindClass methods or something similar.
I don't know how to do it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE for battery or CPU temperature. TYPE_TEMPERATURE is the depcrecated constant.

```
public class TempSensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
private final Sensor mTempSensor;

public TempSensorActivity() {
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 mTempSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
}

protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
}
```

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) to refer

Comment: thank you for you advice .<br>I will try to use these calss on JNI

Comment: You have been wrong, TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE not for CPU temperature. It's ambient temperature and have in Galaxy S4 and Moto X